# C# Program with Admin permission is not starting at windows

Tags: c#, autostart, admin-rights

How to make autostart programmatically with admin permission? I tried

```
using (var registryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers", true))
+            {
+                registryKey.SetValue(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath, "RUNASADMIN");
+                registryKey.Flush();
+                registryKey.Close();
+            }
```

But even UAC window does not appear.

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, use a service.

Comment: Service from the current user not work properly.

Comment: You need to make the service talk to a non-admin local process.

Comment: I don't understand. How to achive admin rights for apps with service?